# Properties of Double.NaN and why does Integer wrapper not have an NaN data memeber?

Tags: java

```
i=Double.NaN
while(i==i)
{
//some code
}
```

what is the output?
Why don't we have a `Integer.NaN`?

Answer (score 3):

IEEE floating points have a "Not a Number" representation by spec. Integral types do not have such a state. Every possible binary representation of an integer is a real number.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the output?

There is no output  because NaN != NaN as per the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard, so the loop will never be entered.

> Why don't we have a Integer.NaN?

Because Integers are based on a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary representation where every bit pattern is a valid integer, and none have any special meaning.

Comment: how are we supposed to handle the situation in case of integers??

Comment: @ashutoshsrinet: typically by using the Integer wrapper class with a null value.

Comment: @Michael, or by just using long. Wrappers too expensive.

Comment: @bestsss; long won't help you at all for this purpose. And wrappers are not expensive unless you create millions of them.

Comment: I might be getting it wrong but the idea of NaN is representing a value that doesn't belong to the set of float/double. You can do the same w/ long, for instance any long>Integer.MAX_VALUE (or <MIN_VALUE) is effectively not an int (so it can be considered NaN/null). Wrappers used instead of regular first-class primitives are definitely more expensive, besides the extra memory they cost an indirection to fetch the value.

Comment: @bestsss: The difference is that NaN is part of the standard and will be treated specially by all language builtins and libraries, same as null. Treating all longs>Integer.MAX/MIN_VALUE specially is something only you know about, and which you'll have to remember to do everywhere. Frankly, it's one of the worst programming ideas I've ever heard of. As for wrappers being "expensive": premature micro-optimization.

Comment: well, about wrappers they still have to be checked for null each time, while NaNs are automatically propagated with any operation. As for the worst ideas, I use long instead for encoding ints w/ delta 'compression' and stop bit. Going out of range (albeit not-null) is definitely an error, also it can encode null (via -0 for instance). I'd not recommend do use it for API alike directly but for network stuff, it does the job nicely. Usually lacking a value (aka null/nan) is related w/ broader state that should account the int, itself.

Answer (score 2):

`Double.NaN == x` is always `false`, no matter what `x` is.

Answer (score 0):

For `float` and `double` NaN is not equal to anything even itself.

For `int` and `long` types I have used MIN_VALUE as a value like NaN, but you have to code this yourself, if you want it to work this way.

BTW: There is a puzzler, when is the following an infinite loop.

```
while(x != x + 0);
```

There are three types for `x` when this is an infinite loop.

Another is when is this an infinite loop.

```
while(x == -x);
```

There is 16 type/value combinations for this, much more than you might expect. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! can u answer the first one for me...!

Comment: You should have two types/values already. Hint: the third type supports `+`, but not `-`, `*` or `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you why but you can work around it with this:

`(int)Double.NaN;`

so my guess is that there is not a good reason.